# How to persist a Inheritance relation with repeated column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I Have this code with inheritance Relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PERSON_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 4)

public abstract class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID_PERSON_ID")
private Long id;

...other attributes
}

@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "STUD")
public class Student extends Person implements Serializable{

@OneToMany(targetEntity = ListingRatings.class, mappedBy = "student", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<ListingRatings> listingRatings;

...other attributes

}

@Entity
@Table(name="LISTING_RATING")
public class ListingRatings implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID_LISTING_RATING_ID")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Teacher .class, optional = false )
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID_PERSON_ID",                      insertable=true , updatable=true )
private Teacher teacher;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Student.class, optional = false )
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID_PERSON_ID")
private Student student;

...other attributes
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TEACHER")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="TEAC")
public class Teacher extends Person implements Serializable{

@OneToMany(targetEntity = ListingRatings .class, mappedBy = "teacher",    fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ListingRatings> listingRatings ;

}
```

When i try to persist this relation, I have this Exception

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
cl.programarte.gym.model.ListingRatings
column: ID_PERSON_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

I do not know if this is possible. 
Changing, insertable = true, updatable = true to insertable = false, updatable = false, everything works fine. 
However I need to persist the id of teacher, but this does not.

Maybe is possible to make a composite key for this case? 
It is recommended for you?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you using a the same join column name to map 2 different associations? You obviously need 2 different columns, since the teacher of a ListingRatings is not the same person as its student.

Comment: Thank you very much, after posting the question, I discovered the error I had. 
Best Regards